# Vosk-api python for speech-recognition. Feature for google-like speech adaption?

Tags: python-3.x, google-speech-to-text-api, vosk

So Vosk-api is a brilliant offline speech recogniser with brilliant support, however with very poor (or smartly hidden) documentation, at the moment of this post (14 Aug, 2020)

The question is: is there any kind of replacement of **google-speech-recognizer** feature, which allows additional transcription improvement by speech adaptation?

E.g.

```
"config": {
    "encoding":"LINEAR16",
    "sampleRateHertz": 8000,
    "languageCode":"en-US",
    "speechContexts": [{
      "phrases": ["weather"]
    }]
}
```

For Google this config means that phrase **weather** will have more priority, with respect to, say, **whether** which sounds the same.

Or class tokens?
I understand that it may not be implemented in Vosk for python3, but still...

Here are references:

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/class-tokens

---

https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/speech-adaptation

Comment: [Guillermo Ruiz Camauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14165100) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67084157) saying "You can send Vosk a list of expected words in a phrase_list. See example here: [https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-server/blob/master/websocket/test_words.py](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-server/blob/master/websocket/test_words.py)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow this document for information on Vosk model adaptation:

https://alphacephei.com/vosk/adaptation

Basically there are 4 levels:

1. Update small model with [list of words to recognize](https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api/blob/master/python/example/test_words.py)
2. Update small model offline [with the language model from texts](https://alphacephei.com/vosk/adaptation)
3. Update language model and the dictionary [inside the big model](https://chrisearch.wordpress.com/2017/03/11/speech-recognition-using-kaldi-extending-and-using-the-aspire-model/)
4. Finetune acoustic [model on your data](https://github.com/daanzu/kaldi-active-grammar/issues/33)

The process is not fully automated, but you can ask in the group for help.